# __block variable returns null. How can I access the NSString inside the __block variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am using this findAllMessages() function to return a NSString with information about each message. 
Everything goes well until I go outside of the block and the concatenatedMessage string is null.

The last three lines concatenatedMessage return null:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",concatenatedMessage);
 NSString *newString = concatenatedMessage;
 return newString;
```

How can I access the value of concatenatedMessage outside of the block so that concatenatedMessage is not null?

```
+(NSString *) findAllMessages{

    __block NSMutableArray *totalMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    __block NSDictionary *values;
    __block NSString *concatenatedMessage;

    FIRUser *current_user = [[FIRAuth auth] currentUser];
    FIRDatabaseReference *dbReference = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Messages"] child:current_user.uid];
    FIRDatabaseQuery *allMessages = [dbReference queryOrderedByChild:current_user.uid];

    [allMessages observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSMutableDictionary *eachMessage = snapshot.value;
        concatenatedMessage = @"";
        for(id key in eachMessage){
            [totalMessages addObject:key];
            values = [eachMessage objectForKey:key];
            for(id key2 in values){
                concatenatedMessage = [concatenatedMessage stringByAppendingString:[values objectForKey:key2]];
                concatenatedMessage = [concatenatedMessage stringByAppendingString:@"^^"];
            }
            concatenatedMessage = [concatenatedMessage stringByAppendingString:@"%%"];
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",concatenatedMessage);
    NSString *newString = concatenatedMessage;
    return newString;
}
```

THANKS!!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to wrap an async function (`observeEventType:withBlock:`) with a synchronous function (`findAllMessages`).

This just doesn't work. It seems to be an issue in every modern language.

You can either:

1. Find a synchronous method on `FIRDatabaseQuery` and call that (DON'T do this from the main thread or you will block the UI)
2. Change `findAllMessages` to be asynchronous (`findAllMessagesWithBlock:`) and return to the caller via block. You may need to modify the caller to be async too. Async has a way of taking over big portions of codebases that use it.

Comment: To add to this, If you **really** need to wrap an asynchronous call with a synchronous one (to reiterate, though, "having to" do this is probably a sign of a poor design), you can always use a condition/semaphore variable to prevent the post-block-execution code from executing until signaling it to do so from within the block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how the block works. Let me elaborate:

Your definition of `concatenatedMessage` above the block is correct. Doing something like what you did will allow you to access it *within and outside of the block*:

```
__block NSString *concatenatedMessage;
```

The key here is to understand that your block passed into `...withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {` will most likely **not be executed immediately as blocks are asynchronous**.

That being said, when you log `concatenatedMessage` in your code *after* the block, the block has **not yet been executed**, thus the string isn't changed.

Instead, what you should be doing is either:

1. Not be using a block (use something synchronous like a normal function instead)
2. Do whatever you need to do with `concatenatedMessage` *inside* the block at the end of it so that when the block *is eventually executed*, you code executes after the variable is set